# PHP Variable from another file without include or session

Tags: php, ajax

I've tried using $_SESSION and include, none which have worked. What I'm doing is uploading an image to my server. Using Ajax to run a file called upload.php which has the upload script in it. When the file gets uploaded I want to pass the filename to my main.php page to use as a php variable. Include would just throw errors of undefined variables and session just wouldn't work.

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', '#file', function(){
        var name = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name;
        var form_data = new FormData();
        var ext = name.split('.').pop().toLowerCase();

        var oFReader = new FileReader();
        oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("file").files[0]);
        var f = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
        var fsize = f.size||f.fileSize;

        if(fsize < 4000000)
        {
            form_data.append("file", document.getElementById('file').files[0]);

            $.ajax({
                url:"upload.php",
                method:"POST",
                data: form_data,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#image_upload_info').html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**Part of the upload script, $imagenameupload is the variable I want to pass back to my main.php page**

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo '<div class="container">';
            echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-md-8">';
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">';
                    echo "Pilt: ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " on lisatud!";
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        $imageNameUpload = basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    }
```

**EDIT**
I explained it a little rought before. I want to be able to insert said variable into a database with other data. Heres a little more code.

**SQL INSERT**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Tallinn');
        $typeSelector = $_POST['typeSelector'];
        if (isset($_POST['regionSelector']) ? $_POST['regionSelector'] : null) {
            $checkBox = implode(',', $_POST['regionSelector']);
        }

        if(isset($_SESSION['imageNameUpload'])) {
            $uploadedPic = $_SESSION['imageNameUpload'];
        }

        $now = new DateTime();
        $timestring = $now->format('d.m.Y H:i');
        $_POST = array_map('stripslashes', $_POST);
        //$_POST = json_decode(stripslashes(json_encode($_POST)), true);
        extract($_POST);
        if($title ==''){
            $error[] = 'Pealkiri on puudu.';
        }
        if($newstext ==''){
            $error[] = 'Uudise sisu on puudu.';
        }
        if ($checkBox == '') {
            $error[] = 'Regioon on puudu.';
        }
        if(!isset($error)){
            try {
                $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO news (title,shortdesc,newstext,tag,region,publish_date,imageName) VALUES (:title, :shortdesc, :newstext, :tag, :region, :publish_date, :imageName)') ;
                $stmt->execute(array(
                    ':title' => $title,
                    ':shortdesc' => $shortdesc,
                    ':newstext' => $newstext,
                    ':tag' => $typeSelector,
                    ':region' => $checkBox,
                    ':imageName' => $imageName,
                    ':publish_date' => $timestring
                ));
                header('Location: index.php?news=addednews');
                exit;
            } catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use session in upload.php. Just make sure to do session_start() before any output.

Comment: Look at the next answer and my comment.

Answer (score 0):

In upload.php

First you must start the seesion via session_start(); 
directly after the opening PHP 'tag' ()

Then you must save your variable to the session. 
You can do this like,

```
$_SESSION['imageNameUpload'] = $imageNameUpload;
```

For main.php

And in the other file you must also use session_start(); at the very first after the

Then you could access the old variable via $imageNameUpload = $_SESSION['imageNameUpload'];.

You now can also use $imageNameUpload in the main.php file. But you only can use it if it's set (and you where at the first file before).

upload.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo '<div class="container">';
            echo '<div class="row">';
                echo '<div class="col-md-8">';
                    echo '<div class="alert alert-success">';
                    echo "Pilt: ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " on lisatud!";
                    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
        $imageNameUpload = basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
        $_SESSION['imageNameUpload'] = $imageNameUpload;
    }
```

main.php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['imageNameUpload'])) {
    $imageNameUpload = $_SESSION['imageNameUpload'];
} 

// Other content of file
?>
```

If you don't want to refresh the page after image upload just want to show the uploaded image name without refreshing the page

Then,Change in your upload.php

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    $imageNameUpload = basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    $data = '<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md-8"><div class="alert alert-success">Pilt: '. $imageNameUpload. ' on lisatud!</div></div></div></div>';
    echo $data;
    exit();
}
```

And if you want to refresh the page then show image name on main.php. In that case you have to store data in session as i explain above. and add page refresh statement in ajax success block. And check in main.php if isset $imageNameUpload varible then first show it on html and then unset it. SO it will not seen in another page refresh request.

Hope this helps

Comment: I tried the exact thing you suggested before. Im running into weird things like, when I submit the image, I am not getting the variable and after I refresh the page I get it and it stays there permanently. I think the prolem is where I'm setting the variable and using it in the main.php file and I should also unset it or redirect with exit.

Comment: I'll explain my end goal. I want to insert that variable into a database. So when user might add an image, I want to save that imagename as a variable to then insert into a database with other data. Cause currently when I add an image and it gets uploaded to the server and then I fill out the form and press submit its not inserting the variable. I'll update my answer with more code. My bad explaining myself bad.